# How do you set the Java classpath in eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, git, egit, gitlab

I am having trouble importing a project from git into eclipse as a Java project.

Existing questions say to import it from git, then modify the .project file to change it into a Java project. I was able to do that. But then you have to change the .classpath file. Most answers recommend doing this through eclipse instead of directly modifying the file. To do that they (and eclipse docs) say to go to Project > Properties > Java Build Path. I do not have the Java Build Path option under properties. I have Eclipse Juno.

Comment: How do you [import the project](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Ftasks-importproject.htm)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you are trying to import a non-eclipse project.

1. Create a new project and give it whatever name you want, like
   "client abc". If you already have a folder in the workspace file
   system named "client abc" then name your project something else like
   "client abc whatever".
2. Now close Eclipse and open explorer (if you're using Windows)
3. drag the ".buildpath" and ".project" files as well as the
   ".metadata" folder from the new project folder ("client abc
   whatever") into the actual client folder ("client abc"). Now just
   delete the "client abc whatever" folder.

http://www.dennisplucinik.com/blog/2009/12/22/how-to-import-an-existing-non-eclipse-project-into-eclipse/

Comment: Thanks, thats what I had been trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your project is a Java project, not just a normal project.  Try to re-create the project again, choosing `File -> New ... -> Java Project`.

Comment: It's not currently a Java project. I am trying to import a git repository from gitlab. It doesn't have any of the project info associated with it, so I need to convert it to a java project.